# How to work with infinity arguments in a function (like PHP's isset())

Tags: php, function, parameters, parameter-passing, param

You know how PHP's `isset()` can accept multiple (no limit either) arguments?

Like I can do:

```
isset($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8,$var9,$var10,$var11);
//etc etc
```

How would I be able to do that in my own function? How would I be able to work with infinity arguments passed?

How do they do it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) will do what you want:

```
function infinite_parameters() {
    foreach (func_get_args() as $param) {
        echo "Param is $param" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

You can also use `func_get_arg` to get a specific parameter (it's zero-indexed):

```
function infinite_parameters() {
    echo func_get_arg(2);
}
```

But be careful to check that you have that parameter:

```
function infinite_parameters() {
    if (func_num_args() < 3) {
        throw new BadFunctionCallException("Not enough parameters!");
    }
}
```

You can even mix together `func_*_arg` and regular parameters:

```
function foo($param1, $param2) {
    echo $param1; // Works as normal
    echo func_get_arg(0); // Gets $param1
    if (func_num_args() >= 3) {
        echo func_get_arg(2);
    }
}
```

But before using it, think about whether you *really* want to have indefinite parameters. Would an array not suffice?

Comment: array is less convinient in use. For example, I often replace isset() with empty(), which accept only one arg. So I often declare function mempty() that can take many arguments but is as convinient, as isset. Nice anwser BTW.

Answer (score 46):

Starting with PHP 5.6 you can use the token "**...**"

Example:

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
```

Source:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: The original answer should be updated to include this. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `func_get_args()`, it will return an array of arguments.

```
function work_with_arguments() {
    echo implode(", ", func_get_args());
}

work_with_arguments("Hello", "World");
//Outputs: Hello, World
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `func_get_args()` inside of your function will return an array of the arguments passed to PHP.